# Android SDK Manager refusing to open

Tags: android, sdk

The cmd flashes but then goes away. I've edited the following to android.bat

```
set java_exe="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
set javaw_exe="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe"
set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar
rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
set swt_path=lib\x86_64
```

I've tried running as administrator.
I've set the JAVA_HOME path

currently using SDK version 1.7.0_51
and jre7

I Run my Android.bat in cmd and get this output.

```
C:\>C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools\android.bat
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-client       to select the "client" VM
-server       to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is client.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I found that none of the "set" commands in  beginning of the batch file worked correctly. 
 prog is set to ~f0. 
 work_dir is empty 
 cd /d ~dp0 results in an error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

**Android.bat requires command extensions enabled in order to run correctly.**

Edit this line in the original android.bat
from...
   setlocal 
to...
  setlocal **enableExtensions**

This should set all the environment variables correctly so that they don't need to be hard coded.

You can also enable command extensions in the registry.  Reboot after making this change. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions = 1

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but may help for anyone who still can't fix this issue, follow these step and it help for me after a long time with all ways above not effect, no need to have JAVA_HOME system variable or edit android.bat

1. Download Android Studio within Android SDK, Java JDK 64 bits and Java JRE x86
2. Install Java JRE first, then install Java JDK 64 bits, and the Android Studio last.
3. Now you start Android Studio first (64 bits version) it require to have JAVA_HOME setting to run JVM, just copy the jdk.x.x.x(version) folder (my PC: jdk1.8.0_25 from "C:\Program Files\Java\")folder to Android Studio folder and rename that folder (in Android Studio) to "jre" (jdk1.8.0_25 -> jre).
4. Now it work for me to open Android SDK Manager from anywhere, if you want to use eclipse (not official now) just copy the java jre.x.x.x(version) x86 folder (from where you install before) to Eclipse and rename to "jre". After coping, choose the Android SDK path in Eclipse to use, It works for both Android Studio and Eclipse.
5. Mind your antivirus if it still refusing you (remove antivirus and install after you sure it not cause problem)!

Hope it help for you.